# How to configure Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, appearance, system-settings

I cannot find a place like control panel in Windows where I can configure Ubuntu. I would be delighted to find where to configure the system. And by the way, how to use the configure Ubuntu according to my own appetite?

Comment: 3 minutes to ask another question? Try searching for a "beginner's guide"

Answer (score 7):

From Unity Dash you can search System Setting.

[image]

**System Setting**

[image]

**Advance Setting / Gnome Tweak Tool / Tweak Tool**

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

**Ubuntu Tweak**

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak -y
```

Comment: Very good screenshots.

Comment: Its a lil bit blur, using shutter. Will upload another image soon ;)

Comment: I'd also add Unity-tweak and Gnome-tweak, if applicable.

Comment: @penreturn oops! I didn't notice your answer.

Comment: its okey @devav2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use System settings to tweak Ubuntu settings.

To open **System settings**

Open dash and search for "System Settings"
[image]

or

open terminal( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) and type `gnome-control-center`

[image]

This will help you to configure your Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Click the gear-cog icon in the top right of your screen, and click "System Settings", here you will find a control-panel equivalent, as in Windows. Here is a link describing each setting: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/prefs.html

I hope this helps